# Rails - Using Font Awesome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I include a fontawesome icon within my button?

```
<%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-large' %>
```

I tried

```
<%= f.submit '<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>Post'.html_safe, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-large' %>
```

But it doesn't display the icon properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try making the text HTML safe? In any case, you can also use a block to define the button content, IIRC.

Comment: Comment on his answer, not the question. If you got text you didn't put in the block them something else is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Rails 4 or newer, you can pass a block to the submit method and include your HTML in there.

Try this:

```
<%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-large' do %>
  <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Post ...
<% end %>
```

See this GitHub issue for more details:
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/745